# Python Itertools groupby - writing lines to csv file

Tags: python-3.x, group-by

I am new to Python, apologies if this is a stupid question.
I have a text file with the following input:

- Apple   Apple1
- Apple   Apple2
- Aaron   Aaron1
- Aaron   Aaron2
- Aaron   Aaron3
- Tree    Tree1

I have the following code:

```
import csv
import sys
from itertools import groupby

with open('File.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    next(reader, None)
    a = [[k] + [x[1]  for x in g] for k, g in groupby(reader, key=lambda row: row[0])]
    sys.stdout=open('Out.txt','w', encoding='utf-8')
    print (str(a))
```

What I want to achieve:

- Apple Apple1,Apple2
- Aaron Aaron1,Aaron2,Aaron3
- Tree  Tree1

However, the output I am now getting is in list form, while I want it to be printed line per line. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('File.txt',delimiter=' ' , header=None)
grouped = df.groupby(0).agg(lambda col: ', '.join(col)).to_records()

for group in grouped:
    print(group[0] + ' ' + group[1])
```